# Parse a Bundle which is a JSONString in Remotemessage to JSON object

Tags: javascript, java, android, json, stringify

I am trying to parse the notification data in FCM. I will try to explain my problem as detailed as i can. I have to two apps one is android and the other is javascript webapp. so when sending pushnotification from webapp to androd app I am sending the notification data in jsonstring format. Now i am unable to convert it to JSONObject on the java side(android). Below is my code

```
    var notification = {
    'TITLE': currentUser.displayName,
    'MSG': message,
    'CHAT_KEY': chatKey,
    'MSG_KEY': 'messageKey',
    'USER_DISPLAY_NAME': currentUser.displayName,
    'USER_EMAIL': currentUserEmail, 
    'USER_FCM_DEVICE_ID': toKey,
    'USER_FCM_DEVICE_ID_SENDER': fromKey,
  };

  fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'key=' + fromKey,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'body': JSON.stringify({
      'notification': notification,
      'to': toKey
    })
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  })
};
```

And on the android side

```
@Override public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {


        sendDefaultNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    } else {
        String currentUserEmail = "";
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null && auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail() != null) {
            currentUserEmail = auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        }

        String userName = remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.KEY_USER_DISPLAY_NAME);
        String userEmail = remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.KEY_USER_EMAIL);
        String chatKey = remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.KEY_CHAT_KEY);
        String deviceId = remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.KEY_USER_FCM_DEVICE_ID);
        String deviceIdSender = remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.KEY_USER_FCM_DEVICE_ID_SENDER);
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.KEY_MSG_TITLE);
        String msg = remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.KEY_MSG);
        String msgKey = remoteMessage.getData().get(Constants.KEY_MSG_KEY);

        /*if (chatKey.equals(ConstantsFirebase.FIREBASE_LOCATION_CHAT_GLOBAL)) {
            title = String.format("%s- %s", title, ConstantsFirebase.CHAT_GLOBAL_HELPER);
        } else {*/
            if (!currentUserEmail.equals(Utils.decodeEmail(userEmail))) {
                setMessageReceived(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child(ConstantsFirebase.FIREBASE_LOCATION_CHAT).child(chatKey).child(msgKey)
                        .child(ConstantsFirebase.FIREBASE_PROPERTY_MESSAGE_STATUS));
            }
      /*  }*/

        boolean notificationIsActive = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .getBoolean(Constants.KEY_PREF_NOTIFICATION, false);
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null && notificationIsActive) {
            if (!currentUserEmail.equals(Utils.decodeEmail(userEmail))) {

                Utils.setAdditionalData(new PushNotificationObject
                        .AdditionalData(title, msg, chatKey, msgKey, userName,
                        userEmail, deviceId, deviceIdSender));
                sendNotification(title, msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am considering the Remotemessage directly as JSONObject but it's coming in bundle jsonstring. How do I parse it?

Output:

```
Bundle[{gcm.notification.USER_DISPLAY_NAME=ishku sukshi, google.sent_time=1512190657773, gcm.notification.TITLE=ishku sukshi, gcm.notification.USER_FCM_DEVICE_ID=fXLDo7zU7c0:APA91bFx0sIGwIZ9jIm7xi7QvSrWKrL29uWJnNT0jujlyVHTScUteuRZ37nB-FgEeBXokZdQfmyGKhhRLjCILraS8sTif4p6DRJ_jZkNlh-J_yhKTAU3WnBYzGBtlaTorcAJhDtd1AIy, gcm.notification.CHAT_KEY=-L-FVx8eZBuz-QIsnXvx, from=1028795933953, gcm.notification.USER_EMAIL=ishkumihu@gmail,com, google.message_id=0:1512190657780774%bfd1fc79bfd1fc79, gcm.notification.MSG_KEY=messageKey, gcm.notification.MSG=, gcm.notification.USER_FCM_DEVICE_ID_SENDER=AAAA74kEJQE:APA91bHN5lJf0S8KNXzhU4XL1rz1rqyZ6ziY4UghZudtW6iH84ytQksWMSvSKsaBqQEsw7P2txk-yTGp5DOYElb7pdg8VFgj8wecJUcsPKJ6JCASCO_ihXh6xpo3a2aDuw8HnHPvL0Mr, collapse_key=com.sukshi.sukshichat}]
```

Actually gcm.notification appending each key also should not come , I don't know why that's coming.

[image]

Comment: What is the error you get? You want to convert your remote message into JSONObject? You actually don't need this, you can get the value of JSON in this case also?

Comment: But the data I ma getting is in JSONSTRING format. How can i get values of json from jsonstring?

Comment: You need to have the JSON or you only need the values. `String userName = data.get(Constants.KEY_USER_DISPLAY_NAME.name()).toString()` this might work for you?

Comment: I need to have the json

Comment: Please print remoteMessge#getData() and add output to question, so that we can see what type of data you're receiving.

If it's a json string, you can convert it into JSON Object by using 
: JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

Comment: @dpaksoni I edited the que with my output. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with making `JSONObject` from string representation of json. Change you `notification` to `data` on server side code. Like -

```
fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'key=' + fromKey,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'body': JSON.stringify({
      'data': notification,
      'to': toKey
    })
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  })
};
```

And get your fcm message on Android side -

```
String body = remoteMessage.getData();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(body );
Log.d("json", json.toString());
```

Then you can get value by key assigned from javascript. Like - `json.get("USER_DISPLAY_NAME");`

And let me know how its going.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference 

This is the error I am getting if I implement your way.

Comment: can you post what `remoteMessage.getNotification()` with `toString()` gives?

Comment: is it possible to connect with you personally? Like on skype or hangouts? I've been struggling with this problem for the last 3 days

Answer (score 3):

Actually you're getting Map object from RemoteMessage#getData() method.
So if you need a json object, what you can do is create it on your own like below

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
//data is RemoteMessage#getData();
Set<String> keys = data.keySet();
for (String key : keys) {
    try {
       json.put(key, JSONObject.wrap(data.get(key)));
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        //Handle exception here
  }
}
```

Comment: Please accept answer if it really solved your problem.

Comment: By using this I get keys = 0
I am adding a pic of my output in the picture.